# Can I force a subclass to an abstract baseclass with fields to override equals?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have this:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    private int x;

    // Auto generated via the IDE
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        BaseModel baseModel = (BaseModel) o;
        return x == baseModel.x;
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    private int foo;

    // Auto generated via the IDE
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        MyClass that = (MyClass) o;
        return Objects.equals(foo, that.foo);
    }
}
```

The problem I have now, is that if I don't implement `MyClass:equals`, then I will get the wrong result when comparing instances of `MyClass`. So I thought that I want to force `MyClass` to override the `equals` method. How do I do that?

I tried making `BaseClass::equals` abstract, but then I could of course not call it via `super`.

I was also considering renaming `BaseClass::equals` to `BaseClass::equalsAux` and then call `super.equalsAux` but I want to be able to autogenerate the `equals` method for subclasses.

I'm completely open to the thought that I may have approached this problem from the completely wrong angle. Should I just trust people who inherit from this class to implement it on their own?

Comment: I would trust people their own classes to provide their own equals method (or at least I would assert that if they don't do that, they shouldn't expect equals to take account of their extra fields). Whether you _should_ trust people to do that is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Unless subclass of ```BaseClass``` can be equal, you should not override ```equals``` in an abstract class.  There is no requirement to override ```equals```.  If you do not override ```equals``` then the version defined in ```Object``` will be used.   Finally if you do override ```equals``` you should also override ```hashcode```